# Initial value for JQuery Datepicker from the definition

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Is there a way to have the current date pre-selected and **visible** 
in jQuery DatePicker, just from the definition?

I know there are several ways to call events and extra setters after the Picker is visualized. But I'm using with a **PHP wrapper** (Yii/jui) adding extra JS operations outside of the definition is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <input type="text" id="datepickers">
    $("#datepickers").datepicker({}); // Initialize
    $("#datepickers").datepicker('setDate', new Date()); // Set the current date
```

Comment: the second row is making a function call on the already initialized DatePicker. I need a way to make it work just from the definition

Comment: I tried like this, only for the input element "datepickers", today's date is set. `<input type="text" id="datepickers">
<input type="text" id="datepickerss">                  $("#datepickers").datepicker({}); // Initialize
$("#datepickers").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
$("#datepickerss").datepicker({});`